# Toggle float macro together with int* - What does it do?

Tags: c++, opencv, casting, ieee-754, feature-extraction

I am trying to understand the AKAZE feature implementation in OpenCV and was baffled when I came accross the following macro:

```
/* IEEE754 constants and macros */
#define  CV_TOGGLE_FLT(x) ((x)^((int)(x) < 0 ? 0x7fffffff : 0))
```

It is used in the MLDB binary comparisons in the following way (I removed all irrelevant parts of the code):

```
void MLDB_Binary_Comparisons(float* values)
{
    int* ivalues = (int*)values;
    for (int i = 0; i < count * chan; i++)
        ivalues[i] = CV_TOGGLE_FLT(ivalues[i]);

    /* ... The ivalues are then compared to each other using the > operator */
}
```

Does anyone understand what's going on here? Is it really safe to cast a float* to an int*, and what on earth does the macro do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it just extracts ints from float in specific format. It is hard to say more as it require to analyze more code than you provided. Please check this link, maybe it will be clearer for you if you check the float format.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence, it does some binary manipulation of the floating-point data, in a non-portable fashion: there are clearly assumptions about the relative sizes of `int` and `float` and also about their representation. I think that **if** `int` is a 32-bit 2's-complement integer, and `float` is an IEEE 32-bit floating point value, then it lets you compare the floating point values using only integer operations.

In more detail...

```
int* ivalues = (int*)values;
```

This just gives us a pointer that is used to walk through the floating-point values. They are *interpreted* as `ints`, not *converted* to `int` - in other words there is no reason to think that a `float` with a value of `1.0` will map to an `int` value of `1`.  So the main thing you can do is bitwise operations, or specific manipulations which rely on understanding the binary format used for `float`.

Looking at the macro...

```
#define  CV_TOGGLE_FLT(x) ((x)^((int)(x) < 0 ? 0x7fffffff : 0))
```

The value `x` (remember, just some of the bits which otherwise represent a floating point value, but here we are just looking at it as a bit pattern) is XOR-ed with either `0` (which has no effect) or `0x7fffffff` (which inverts the low-order 31 bits). The decision of what to do is based on whether `x` is less than zero or not.

I think this macro is based on the assumption that an `int` is a 32-bit 2's-complement representation. That means that `x < 0` is true if the top bit is set. The XOR with `0x7fffffff` will invert the other bits. This will mean that `-1`, the most positive negative number, is changed from `0xffffffff` to `0x8000000`, which is the most negative negative number (`-2147483648`) and likewise `0x8000000` becomes `0xffffffff`.  When you use `>` after this to compare two negative numbers, it means that what was the *more negative* number is now the *more positive* number, and the "greater than" branch will be taken. Comparing two positive numbers is unchanged, and comparing a positive number to a negative number the positive number is, as you'd expect, still always greater.

This lets you do comparisons for `float`s using only integer operations. This is because the way `float`s, in IEEE format, store negative numbers is quite different from 2's-complement: the sign bit is really just a flag that the value is positive or negative, and the remaining bits store the magnitude of the number. Once you have applied the `CV_TOGGLE_FLT(x)` you don't have values you can use directly, but they are ordered in the same fashion as the original `float` values.

Comment: @4-bit Thanks, glad to have been able to help. And it was fun trying to find out what was going on!